# Figma svg exporting issues

Tags: html, css, svg, figma

Currently I use Figma to make models for my animations but the thing is whenever I export the svg file from it, I don't seem to have paths therefore I can't make my triangles , rectangles, circles, etc.. hoverable, clickable.. I've tried every option that Figma has and I can't figure it out.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Can you update your question with a small example of the sort of SVG files you are getting?

Comment: Can you give me a link to a sample Figma file containing the shapes you're exporting to SVG?

You also need to tell us what tool you're using to animate those SVG's.